# C# Navigating an OpenVMS Menu using a Telnet Connection

Tags: c#, telnet, openvms

I have a (.NET) C# Application (Framework v4.5) which performs a TELNET connection to an OpenVMS machine and is able to successfully login.

In order to login to the machine I'm reading the TELNET client stream output buffer, and searching for the "Username: " and "Password: " strings. Afterwards, the appropriate commands are being sent. I'm ending each input command with the carriage return "\r".

However, I'm not able to retrieve from the TELNET client stream buffer the menu options of the OpenVMS form, which are displayed once the user is logged in. I hoped to use the form to be able to navigate in the OpenVMS machine menu.

Are there any API's I can use to navigate the OpenVMS form with C#?

Comment: Are you sure that it displays the menu after login for the Telnet connection? It could be querying for the type of terminal, e.g. VT132, so that it can format the menu correctly. It might use the terminal port, e.g. TTB9:, to determine what to do. A _network sniffer_ like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) would let you see exactly what is happening on the Telnet connection.

Comment: @HABO Yes, it indeed queries for the terminal type and fails to recognize it ("SET-I-UNKTERM, unknown terminal type"). Shortly after I get a message requesting to input my menu choice. If I was able to recognize the terminal type, would I be able to get the menu from the NetworkStream buffer?

Comment: You can receive the the "inquiry" sequence and reply with a suitable terminal type sequence. The sequences are generally documented as "Device Attributes". [VT510 ANSI Control Functions Summary](https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/chapter4.html) is one reference.